# android error feedback device

Tags: android

I was wondering if there is any way to get any feedback of what's going on behind the scenes when running an app on an Android device. If I use the emulator and eclipse I can see what's happening in the logcat. But I'm making a program with ROS android and it I cannot run it on the emulator. Now my program crashes and I don't know why. Is there any way I can get more information?

Thanks

Comment: you can debug it or connect the device to PC to see error in logcat

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple (less than elegant) ways to try and find out what's going on.

1) Display toasts from potential problem areas (Does it have a screen?)
2) Write logs to the SD card (does it have an SD card??)

**EDIT**

I wasn't thinking clearly... you have to be able to load the program to the device, so you must be able to connect it to your PC.  So, as Agarwal pointed out, you can most likely hook it up, run it on the device/robot/whatever and see what happens with the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

You can use adb to debug the app on your device. See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html